# VB.NET: SHDocVw.WebBrowser.Navigate with URL Data String

Tags: vb.net, activex, business-objects, data-uri

I've exhausted all other methods to deliver this solution.
I'm trying to display a fancy "loading" GIF in my application (an Add-On for a third party piece of software).

I have created a URL Data string for the GIF (and if I navigate to that string in my browser, the gif is displayed correctly).

Now, when I open the browser in my application and navigate to http://google.co.uk, it opens that page perfectly!

However, when I open the data URL, I get the following error:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Here's my code snippet:

```
     Dim iehost As SHDocVw.WebBrowser
                OItem = osysform.Items.Add("axtest", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_ACTIVE_X)
                With OItem
                    .Left = 0
                    .Top = 0
                    .DisplayDesc = True
                    .Width = osysform.ClientWidth - 5
                    .Height = osysform.ClientHeight - 5
                End With
                Dim ox As SAPbouiCOM.ActiveX = OItem.Specific
                ox.ClassID = "Shell.Explorer.2"
                iehost = ox.Object
                iehost.Resizable = True
                iehost.Visible = True
                'iehost.Navigate("http://google.co.uk") 'Works great. - using data URL below fails.
                iehost.Navigate("<Very long URL here, shortened for stackoverflow>")
```

I've left out the URL because it's massive, but the first part of it looks like this:

```
            "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhJQEsAPf/AHFxcfLdsrKy
```

Comment: That's not a URL, that's a [Data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). Not all URIs are URLs. You can't navigate to it. You have to put it in the page in an `<img>` element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vincent. As far as I'm aware though, the .Navigate method is capable of taking a URI as a parameter? See [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161352(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: A URI is not a single thing. There are different types of URIs. From the documentation you linked to: _"A Uri representing the **URL** of the document to load"_ - The `Navigate()` method requires a URI of type _**URL**_. What you have there is a _Data URI_, not a _URL URI_. -- As I said not all URIs are URLs, however all URLs are URIs.